# Documentation of Qt in CHM format

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Is it possible to find some information about Qt? I need chm file with all documentation of all classes (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html). Does somebody knows where can I find it?

Comment: Do you just need offline help or is it essential that the format is chm? Qt SDK contains Qt Assistant, which is the offline help system containing all the Qt documentation.

Comment: @Roku: yes, offline help, but it will be very helpful to receive chm format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the script from this site: http://www.interclasse.com/scripts/chm.php in order to generate chm file from an online tutorial you find anywhere in the web. Like this one: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/nokia-qtsdk-1.0/index.html

I haven't tried it myself, but seems rather promising.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

If you have installed Qt in your machine, use **`Qt Assistant`**. The help available are pretty much the same as that in the online.

**`Qt Assistant`** is just an application **which requires no internet connection** and useful for offline help..

Answer (score 1):

I've made a little script that will automatically build a CHM file out of the latest available documentation for QT. All credits to [char101](https://github.com/char101/qt-documentation-chm) for the main script that actually converts HTML docs into the CHM project, my part was only a little automation.

https://github.com/vzhd1701/qt-documentation-chm-autoupdated